# Error while using cairo devices in R on ubuntu

Tags: r, cairo

I'm working on cairo devices. I'm generating cairo_pdf and getting error message shown below.

```
cairo_pdf("DATA")
Warning messages:
1: In cairo_pdf("DATA") :
  unable to load shared object '/usr/local/lib64/R/library/grDevices/libs//cairo.so':
  /usr/local/lib64/R/library/grDevices/libs//cairo.so: undefined symbol: png_set_longjmp_fn
2: In cairo_pdf("DATA") : failed to load cairo DLL
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you need to reinstall / rebuild that package.

You can also install the earlier cairodevice package which I packaged for Debian via a quick `sudo apt-get install r-cran-cairodevice`.

Comment: I used command sudo apt-get install r-cran-cairodevice. but i m getting some conflict message like 2.6.35-31.24 is to be installed
                                                                   
                                                                    Conflicts: linux-backports-modules-compat-wireless-2.6.37-2.6.35-32-generic but 2.6.35-32.25 is to be installed

Comment: Just to inform my ubuntu version is 11.04.