# Error while using cairo_pdf() on R

Tags: r, runtime-error, redhat

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Error while using cairo devices in R on ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13793763/error-while-using-cairo-devices-in-r-on-ubuntu)

I m getting error message while using cairo_pdf().

> cairo_pdf("sample.pdf")

```
Warning messages:
1: In cairo_pdf("sample.pdf") :
  unable to load shared object '/usr/local/lib64/R/library/grDevices/libs//cairo.so':
  /usr/local/lib64/R/library/grDevices/libs//cairo.so: undefined symbol: png_set_longjmp_fn
2: In cairo_pdf("sample.pdf") : failed to load cairo DLL

OS : RHEL6

R : 2.15
```

How can fix this error?

Regards

Comment: Looks like you need to reinstall / rebuild that package. look here may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13793763/error-while-using-cairo-devices-in-r-on-ubuntu

Answer (score 3):

You have installed the package from your distribution repo or build it from source? It seems to me that the package in the RHEL repository compiled without option `--with-cairo`. Try to build the package from [source](http://cran.r-project.org/src/base/R-2/R-2.15.2.tar.gz) (tarball, ~23 MB).